# Passing an array to server with signalR

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, signalr-hub

How do I pass an array of string in javascript to the server with SignalR?

I have an array in javascript and would like to this to a function to a Hub

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function () {
    selected.push($("input").attr('name'));
});
```

What type of parameter should the function take?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide details with your problem, including sample code, error details, etc. so we can reproduce the exact problem you're having. For other tips on asking good questions, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hub function can take an array of strings, a list of strings etc.

Here's an example hub:

```
public class myHub : Hub
{
    public void receiveList(List<String> mylist) 
    {
        mylist.Add("z");
        Caller.returnList(mylist);
    }
}
```

Here's an example JS piece to work with the hub:

```
var myHub = $.connection.myHub,
    myArray = ['a','b','c'];

myHub.client.returnList = function(val) {
    alert(val); // Should echo an array of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'z'
}

$.connection.hub.start(function() {
    myHub.server.receiveList(myArray);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that the hub can take an array and list.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that you can't have overloads. Such as `receiveList(string myList) {} receiveList(List<String> mylist) {}` you must give them different names, so `receiveList(string myList) {} receiveListWithList(List<String> mylist) {}`